# Optimize ViewPager with RecyclerViews containing heavy data

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a `ViewPager` containing five `Fragment`'s. Each Fragment contains much data. For example the first Fragment is a list of 600 entries containing text and images. The other four `Fragment`'s are containing diagrams which are creating evaluations from the list of the 600 values. The optimizations I implemented yet are:

1. No Database selects inside the adapter
2. No Image Loading inside the adapter (Im using Picasso)
3. No data parsing inside the adapter

I also load the entries for the Adapter inside an `AsyncTask`. For the `RecyclerView`'s i set the following options:

```
this.listRowParent.setItemViewCacheSize(5);
this.listRowParent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
this.listRowParent.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
this.listRowParent.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

The scrolling is very smooth with all my optimizations. The problem that i have is what happens when the fragment becomes visible. The moment when i set the adapter the ui starts freezing (skipping between 100 and 300 frames). I tried to solve it increasing the `OffscreenPageLimit`:

```
this.viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
```

but that just helps sometimes. I guess the interal initialization of the adapter when it is set is performing too much work on the ui thread but i have no idea how i could improve the performance. The only operations i perform inside the adapter and the `onBindViewHolder` methods are comparisons in list initializations.

How can i further improve the performance? Would it be possible for example to place the code inside the `onBincViewHolder` inside an `AsyncTask` or would that not be possible due to the mechanisms of a `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible  to place the code inside the onBincViewHolder inside an AsyncTask.
 you have not provided much code, I can only suggest to separate your UI logic and data processing logic and then perform data processing logic into a worker thread and meanwhile show a progress dialog to user to notify that something is happening in background

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you really have great amount of data and have to some heavy processing over them, `lazy loading` of object is a better approach. Since you have not provided much code, I can only suggest to separate your `UI logic` and `data processing logic` and then perform `data processing logic` into a worker thread and meanwhile show a progress dialog to user to notify that something is happening in background. This would avoid the frustration of UI freezing up.

Other approach could be to load your data in pieces and make use of methods like [`notifyItemRangeInserted()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeInserted(int,%20int)) which are more efficient than simple `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: But isnt this what the recyclerview should do? The 600 values for example are data from the las 3 months. if i only take data from the last week everything is working fast and smooth. So i thought setting `this.listRowParent.setItemViewCacheSize(5);` would do the trick. If not - is there a recyclerview technique which handles the "lazy loading" automatically?